# Sqoop Import - Job stuck while connecting to Resource Manager

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, sqoop

I am trying to import data from sql server to Hive using Sqoop. When I execute the import command, sql server connection is successful but when it comes to connecting to resource manager, the job get stuck. Here is the log:

```
18/07/16 12:35:20 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
18/07/16 12:35:20 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/avro.jar
18/07/16 12:35:20 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/fastutil-6.3.jar
18/07/16 12:35:20 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
18/07/16 12:35:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
```

Here is the sqoop import command:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ip;databaseName=TEST" --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --username user1 --password pass1 --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table "customer_data_march" --table "customer_data_march_parsed" --split-by Account_Branch_Converted -m 1 --verbose
```

When I check the resource manager process allocation, it shows the following:

```
[root@quickstart /]# jps
3527
1609 ThriftServer
850 JobHistoryServer
1135 ResourceManager
2611 HRegionServer
786 Bootstrap
506 NameNode
4225 Jps
3499
950 NodeManager
382 JournalNode
1983 RunJar
3469 Bootstrap
3124 Bootstrap
1745 RunJar
2459 Bootstrap
2493 HistoryServer
248 QuorumPeerMain
1446 HMaster
634 SecondaryNameNode
297 DataNode
```

Here are configurations in yarn-site.xml

```
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.dispatcher.exit-on-error</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>List of directories to store localized files in.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/${user.name}/nm-local-dir</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Where to store container logs.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>Classpath for typical applications.</description>
     <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
     <value>
        $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
        $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*
     </value>
  </property>
<!--
 <property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>

 <property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>

 <property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>
-->
</configuration>
```

After leaving my job for a while, it gives me following error:

```
18/07/16 14:02:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1531745885301_0001 running in uber mode : false
18/07/16 14:02:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/07/16 14:02:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1531745885301_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1531745885301_0001 failed 2 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1531745885301_0001_000002 timed out. Failing the application.
18/07/16 14:02:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
18/07/16 14:02:20 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
18/07/16 14:02:20 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 1,241.2774 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/07/16 14:02:20 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
18/07/16 14:02:20 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
18/07/16 14:02:20 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

I am running the docker using following command:

```
 docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -p 8889:8888 -i 00a03c98e0d2 /u
sr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why does your sqoop client think the resource manager is at `0.0.0.0` rather than an actual network address? Please provide your yarn-site.xml

Comment: I have added to my question

Comment: Can you try changing each of those `127.0.0.1` addresses to `quickstart.cloudera`? Also, if running Sqoop externally, you need to expose many more ports from the container. Also, CDH doesn't include any MSSQL JDBC driver, so it's not clear where you're getting that

Comment: Let me change the host first. There is no issue in connecting to MSSQL server as I have already copied the driver file.

Comment: Copied the driver from where? It's not a docker volume, so it'll be deleted when you restart the container

Comment: I have downloaded the sqljdbc41.jar file from oracle website. And committed the container, so the file won't delete. There is no problem with SQL server connection.